# Fail to spawn Python child process from Node.js server on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, child-process, spawn

I have a node server and I'm  running a python file from it on an endpoint like this:

```
app.get('/api/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.key !== 'key') { res.send('invalid key'); }

    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        py    = spawn('python', ['./python/run.py']),
        file  = 'sdrawkcab.tuo.semoc.eman.elif.siht',
        dataString = '';

    // on receive data
    py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        dataString += data.toString();
    });

    // on data done being sent back
    py.stdout.on('end', function(){
        // responds with 'this.file.name.comes.out.backwards'
        res.send(dataString);
    });

    // pass in file name and run py
    py.stdin.write(file);
    py.stdin.end();
})
```

In python I can `print 'some string'` to return back to node. It works fine locally, but when deployed to heroku the print statement fails to relay to node.

The project is being deployed fine with buildpacks for python and node. The endpoint is able to be hit and `res.send('something')` early.

Is there something i need to set up on heroku to allow for child process spawing between node and python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some output ?